# how to create ubuntu distro from virtual box snapshot and install it as 2nd OS?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, virtualbox, snapshot

i have ubuntu running in vbox in win10. I did some actions -installed software and made snapshot.

Now is it possible to make a distro **with all that saved** work from the snapshot?

- snapshot->iso
- use rufus to make it installable
- dual boot and choose that ubuntu with all presaved stuff?

Is it technically possible?

Comment: @user535733 the linked article is about cloning VM snapshots, not creating a bootable live system from an existing VM snapshot.

Comment: @ERJAN this is of course technically possible, but I suspect it wouldn't have the desired outcome because: if you would just want to clone the VM's state to a "real" installation on your hard disk, you'd use CloneZilla Live or something similar (or do it by hand) without an installer or bootable live system. If, on the other hand, you'd like to create your own distribution that you could hand out to friends or distribute over the internet, you wouldn't start with a "used" VM because that already contains user accounts, logs etc. Ubuntu has good tutorials for creating a customized live system.

Comment: As a side note: if all that saved work consists primarily of installing packages and modifying some files, I'd suggest writing a shell script that automates this process.

Comment: @user535733 AFAIK remastersys is not maintained anymore, and the website is long gone.

Comment: @danzel I think you have a great answer for the OP. Consider writing it up as a real Answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: @danzel, yes pls elaborate on this if you have time sir thx u